# Why the confirmation pass matching stop working when move it to server?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I'm using Rails and jQuery validation plugin : everything working correct in localhost, but somehow password confirmation stops working when I move it to server.

It always says, that passwords didn't match.

Here is code:

```
     'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        'user[password_confirmation]': {
            equalTo: "#user_password", 
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        }
```

My included scripts:

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and html form:

```
  <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password"></div>
  <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

```
equalTo: "user[password]"
```

?